# kdenlive video editor won't start

Tags: videos, video-editor

I installed kdenlive from appcenter but it wouldn't start. so I tried starting it from the terminal, I get the below error.
I am not sure how to fix this issue. Please help.....

> $ kdenlive Gtk-Message: Failed to load module
>   "pantheon-filechooser-module" qrc:/qml/kdenliveclipmonitor.qml:1:1:
>   module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
>   qrc:/qml/kdenliveclipmonitor.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Controls.Styles"
>   is not installed qrc:/qml/kdenliveclipmonitor.qml:1:1: module
>   "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
>   qrc:/qml/kdenliveclipmonitor.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Controls.Styles"
>   is not installed Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Thank you for any help.!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have managed to run kdenlive is by an appimage. Works like a charm. This is what I recommend.

https://kdenlive.org/download/

Latest stable AppImage (17.12.0) is available here:
https://files.kde.org/kdenlive/release/Kdenlive-17.12.0d-x86_64.AppImage.mirrorlist.
To install, just download the file and make it executable, ( chmod +x ) in a terminal, then run it.(or right click > Properties > set Execute on)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install these Qt complements on terminal:

```
sudo apt -y install qml-module-qtquick-controls
```